# Terminate loop if alpha is not detected

Tags: c++

Basically, I want to get input from user only in alphabetic characters. But this part of my code always seems to be skipped. I think it's a problem with the conditional statement but i dont know how to fix it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
int main()
{   
char ch[100];

cout << "Please key in a sentence to get\n\n";
for(int i=0;isalpha(ch[i]);i++)
{
    ch[i]=getchar();
    putchar(ch[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "get input from user only in alphabetic characters"?

Comment: No whitespace charchters, no numbers, etc.

Comment: So your goal is to get a single line of input from the user, then strip that line of all non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: Yes, an input from user, but as soon as user enters a number or space, the loop should be exited.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the way the `for` loop works. This loop:

```
for(int i=0;isalpha(ch[i]);i++)
{
    ch[i]=getchar();
    putchar(ch[i]);
}
```

executes these steps:

1. Initialize `i` to 0
2. Go to step 7 if the element of `ch` at `i` is nonalphabetic (otherwise, continue normally)
3. Assign the result of `getchar()` to the element of `ch` at `i`
4. Print the element of `ch` at `i`
5. Increment `i`
6. Go to step 2
7. End of loop

So every time you check `ch[i]`, you've just incremented `i` to a new value. So `ch[i]` will always be uninitialized in step 2.

To fix this, I'm guessing you'll want to rebuild your loop so that step 2 is instead executed somewhere between steps 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is skipped because the condition is evaluated before entering the loop's body.

It will evaluate 'isalpha( ch[0] )' which could be any value since you didn't initialize your array (specifically the character at index 0).

You could rewrite your for loop like this,

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
    ch[i] = getchar();
    if ( !isalpha( ch[i] ) ) {
        break;
    }
    putchar( ch[i] );
}
```

Comment: Yes, u are rite, it does work that way better. Code is not skipped, however i still have to key enter for keystrokes to be captured and the loop evaluates to the end.

Answer (score 0):

From further reading, i realized it is not immediately possible in C++ because it partly depends on the terminals which are mostly line buffered. Hence, when compiling with windows, including conio.h and using _getch() helps for this specific problem.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{   
char ch[100];

cout << "Please key in a sentence to get\n\n";
for(int i=0;;i++)
{
ch[i]=_getch();
putchar(ch[i]);
if (!isalpha(ch[i]) && ch[i]!=' ') break;
}
return 0;
}
```